# how to use moment n vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

this is the time i get from the backend

```
time: "2023-03-18T14:30:43.925Z"
```

how can i format it to this

```
2023-03-18
```

this my my template

```
 {{  blog.date }}
```

and it returns this

```
2023-03-18T14:30:43.925Z
```

my script

```
computed: {
  moment: function (date) {
    return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  }
},
```

please how can i get just the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vue-moment

```
npm install vue-moment
```

i your main.js file add this

```
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
```

then your component

```
{{ blog.time  | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
computed: {
  moment: function (date) {
    return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  }
},
```

I remember that parameters shouldn't added to functions in `computed`. Vue won't give this parameter to the function, and `date` becomes `undefined`. As a result, `moment` choose to use current date.

---

Perhaps the following would help:

Template:

```
 {{ moment }}
```

Script:

```js
computed: {
  moment: function () {
    return moment(this.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  }
},
```

I'd like to know whether it works.

Comment: it keeps returning the current date which is today's  date .... the date coming from m backend is 18th

Comment: @xander maybe it's because the time from backend is in UTC? What's the timezone there?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```js
computed: {
  formatDate() {
    return (date) => moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
 }
```

```html
<span>
  {{ formatDate(blog.date) }}
</span>
```

dont forget to import moment